# get values from mysql column in php array

Tags: php, mysql

I've a database with several columns. One of the columns is 'name' and stores the name of the companies in the database. Another column ('id') assign a unique id number to each company. The table has a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 4 companies.

I'd like to show the name of the companies in different places in a html document and therefore need to refer to $company_name_1, $company_name_2 etc. However, these variables should always be in the html document, irrespective of whether the companies are in the database. If not in the database, the value shown should be empty.

How can I automatically define the names of the companies with an array and a loop? I want to expand the database at a later stage hence manually defining the four company names is not an option.

Thanks!

```
$result = mysql_query($con, "SELECT name FROM companydetails");
$storeArray = Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$storeArray[] =  $row['name']; 
}
```

And then I would like to use:

```
echo $storeArray[0];
```

to show the first company and

```
echo $storeArray[1];
```

to show the second company. Etc.

Comment: Any attempts so far?

Comment: Yep, I've been trying arrays and loops and manage to show the name of the first company but when I select $company_name[1] or $company_name[2] I receive an error.

Comment: have you tried any coding for this if yes then, share it... ??

Comment: So what is `$company_name`? where do you define this var?

Comment: sorry, have been playing around with the names etc a little. $company_name[0] is my old $storeArray[0]

Comment: So what is the problem, what error you receieve if you have all **proper** codes combined?

Comment: Forget it, I found it. had to use mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before echo first check if the element exists in array. This way there will be no error, something like this

```
 if(count($storeArray)>1)

 echo $storeArray[1];

 else echo "NA";


 if(count($storeArray)>2)

 echo $storeArray[2];
 else echo "NA";
```